# mathematica does not evaluate without internet access?

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, kernel

I am watching the video [Hands-on Start to Mathematica Basic Graphics](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/handsonstart/) and for about 15 minutes I was trying to evaluate $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and each time I encountered errors like:

1. The result can not be shown as XML
2. syntax error, not able to interprete
3. [image: List item]
4. [image: List item]

until I found out that my internet connection has been lost for a while. As soon as I finished fixing the problem and returned to my desk to reavaluate that command, it worked. Do we need internet connection whenever we are working to Mathematica? Then what if there's no connection available?
[image]

Comment: @OleksandrR. oh yes you're true. I had similar problems when using the documentation center. For example whenever I chose **Help>Find selected Function**, I encountered the [error dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K2jHY.png). That is because it needs online access. then there's nothing wrong with my installation of mathematica

Comment: You only need internet access when you use the natural language interface / WolframAlpha. If you're using plain Mathematica functions (except the *Data functions)  you don't need a connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you only need the Internet connection if you are using [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to enter your inputs, because this is a web service. If you had typed the *Mathematica* input

```
Plot[Sin[x]/x, {x, -9.4, 9.4}]
```

rather than

```
graph of sin[x]/x
```

then this would not have happened.

W|A's interpretation of inputs is unpredictable at the best of times, so I would suggest that you don't use it in this way in ordinary circumstances: I think the tutorial is only using it to make you aware that it is possible.

Comment: The problem is sometimes in spite of having access to the internet, I have this problem. For example if I choose a subpod and request it from `Wolfram|Alpha` the [error dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K2jHY.png), Mathematica goes **Not Responding** and then [another error dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj7Rc.png) is shown without letting me do anything and finally [I have to close Mathematica](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jUHni.png)

Comment: anyway what does **requesting a subpod from `Wolfram|Alpha`** mean?

Comment: I have not experienced this problem myself, but it sounds like a bug or glitch with your configuration. In the preferences dialog (under the Edit menu), go to the Internet Connectivity tab and press "Update local indices from Wolfram Research server", run `RebuildPacletData[]`, and then restart *Mathematica*. If it is a paclet problem, this will hopefully solve it. In the same dialog you are given the option to disable Internet access completely, which may also help.

Comment: About the subpods, this is described in the [W|A API reference](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html). It is not really something that a new user should, or should have to, concern themselves with. (In my opinion anyway.)